# Maya python subprocess error "subprocess.py line 555: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, maya

I'm currently trying to get a script to work which should batch export some assets and also render a preview for these.
The DCC is maya and the renderengine is redshift.
Language is python
The script works fine as long as I export one Asset at a time but I cannot pass on multiple asset since the render one rendering process will still run while the next one is trying to be started thus ending the script.
I also tried using a subprocess which doesn't work for some reason.

Code:

```
import subprocess
import RSL_Script_Package.PreviewRender as PreviewRender

subprocess.run([PreviewRender.renderPreview(r"M:\Test","test")],capture_output=True)

print(process)
```

Output:

```
! Initiate preview render...

['pCube4']
# Error: TypeError: file G:\Autodesk\Maya2022\Python37\lib\subprocess.py line 555: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable # 
// Info:  [Redshift] Redshift for Maya 2022 // 
// Info:  [Redshift] Version 3.0.56, Sep 11 2021 // 
// Info:  [Redshift] Rendering frame 1 (1/1) // 
// Info:  [Redshift] Scene translation time: 0.02s // 
// Info:  [Redshift] ================================================================================================= // 
// Info:  [Redshift] Rendering frame 1... // 
// Info:  [Redshift] AMM enabled // 
// Info:  [Redshift] ================================================================================================= // 
// Info:  [Redshift] License acquired // 
// Info:  [Redshift] License for redshift-core 2021.09 (permanent) // 
// Info:  [Redshift]  // 
// Info:  [Redshift] Device 0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090) uses OptiX for ray tracing // 
// Info:  [Redshift]  // 
// Info:  [Redshift] Rendering time: 6.1s (1 GPU(s) used) // 
// Info:  [Redshift] Saved file 'M:\Test\test_Preview.png' in 0.22s // 
// Info:  [Redshift] Frame done - total time for frame 1 (1/1): 6.98s // 
// Info:  [Redshift] Rendering done - total time for 1 frames: 7.02s // 
// Info:  [Redshift] License returned  //
```

When using another function like "dir" it would give me a proper result as seen here:

Code:

```
import subprocess
import RSL_Script_Package.PreviewRender as PreviewRender

subprocess.run(["dir"], shell=True ,capture_output=True)

print(process)
```

Output:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['dir'], returncode=0)
```

I guess it has something to do with this error:

```
# Error: TypeError: file G:\Autodesk\Maya2022\Python37\lib\subprocess.py line 555: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable #
```

But I have no idea why it happens.

Please help :D

Comment: What does `PreviewRender.renderPreview(r"M:\Test","test")` return?

Comment: It needs to return the name of a command to run from the shell. The error message suggests that it returns `None` instead of a command name.

Comment: @Barmar yeah actually it returns nothing so i guess None. I'll try to integrate a return. What exactly do you mean by "the name of a command to run from the shell"?

Comment: You use `subprocess.run()` to execute an external program or shell command line. Since you're calling a function in the argument, it needs to return the name of the program you want to run.

Comment: It seems like you may be confusing the `subprocess` module with`multiprocessing`.

Comment: @barmar maybe... this is the first time i encounter such a problem and the frist time i try to find a solution for it :D also not a very experienced programmer in general